# Tough Trigonometric Identity Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am having trouble solving a trigonometry identity problem. Specifically, I need to solve:

$\dfrac{\sec(x)\sin(x)}{\tan(x)\cot(x)} = \sin^2x$

I tried solving this by turning $\sin^2x$ into it's half-angle equivalent, starting from the original trigonometric identity to get to my answer backwards, etc etc etc for the last 2 hours. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit: So a few of you asked if my problem had some sort of typing error. This isn't my problem specifically; this is a friend of mine's math problem, so I currently have no way of verifying if this was correctly written to me and will check with him tomorrow. After double-checking with the image he sent me, this is correctly written to the information he gave me.

Comment: $\tan x\cot x=?$  And it looks like you can cancel a $\sin x$ term from both sides as well.  But I think there might be a copy error somewhere...

Comment: As written, you are asking to solve $1 = \sin x \cos x$. Is this what you indented?

Comment: So for maximum clarity, this is not a homework problem of my own - I am a student of applied mathematics at college and this problem was brought to me from a friend of mine in Precalculus. So, to abiessu; I have no direct way of verifying if there was a copy error for the time being, and to mixedmath; this is what I intended, yes.

Comment: I think abiessu's right. Are you sure you copied the formula correctly?I worked it out and got tan x. So I'd check that out again if I were you.

Comment: @JoeD This isn't exactly an _identity_. An identity is true $\forall x$. What you're asking is to solve a trigonometric _equation_.

Comment: Even if the problem is written correctly, you should verify what the problem asked you to do with the given equation.  If it asks to prove an identity, there's a problem with the question.  If, on the other hand, it wants you to solve for $x$, that can be arranged.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$\frac{\sec(x)\sin(x)}{\tan(x)\cot(x)}= \frac{\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\sin(x)}{\tan(x)\frac{1}{\tan(x)}} =\tan(x)$$
This is clearly not an identity because in general 
$$ \tan(x)\not =\sin^2(x) $$